# WPF form inheritances issue

Tags: wpf

I have some questions concerning the issue of form inheritance in WPF.
I have read that there is no visual inheritance in WPF Forms.
I would like to write my project as a base form, with other forms inheriting from it.

Some possible solutions were to use `UserControl`, and use it inside the son form.
The problem is that I have to define it again and again in every new form that inherits the base one.

Can I implement it another way, without defining it in the son-form?

Comment: You do realize that WPF uses windows, not forms, right? See the article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx).

Comment: why not define a BaseWindow, then instead of creating "son forms", create "son UserControls". when you need to show a particular "son UserControl", do: `var sonWindow = new BaseWindow { Content = new SonUserControl() };`

Comment: its an option, but i cant really see it on design time.i will take it as an option. thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a style to handle this with *less* markup than a UserControl (you just have to set `Style="{StaticResource myWindowStyle}"` in every Window element).  Using that style you can override the `Template` of a window, putting whatever chrome you like around the window content.  Add a `ContentControl` with `Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"` wherever you want your sepcific Window's content to appear.

Unfortunately you can't apply this to all Windows easily, because setting a generic style will apply only to the base `Window` control, and each of your application's windows will be of a type that derives from `Window`.

**EDIT:**  If you want to specify templated controls in your Window, you can do something like the following with your style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
        <StackPanel>
          <Button>This button will appear on every window</Button>
          <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: hi, i know i am able to use style. but as i see it, its all about the "Style" of the window. i cant really define there controls. am i wrong?

Comment: As I said, you can override the template to add controls.  See my edit for a sample.